# Request using RestSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, restsharp

I am trying to send a simple request using RestSharp to read the text from a webpage using Get Method in Visual Studio 2017 Community ASP.Net MVC (C#) Web API.
But I am getting errors in writing the request. I am only familiar with C# websites and not much familiar with MVC or Core. I am trying the following Code:

```
public void Get(){
   var client = new RestClient("http://www.dictionary.com/browse/computer");
   var request = new RestRequest("http://www.dictionary.com/browse/computer", Method.GET);
   RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
}
```

I am writing this code in`D1Controller`. For debugging I am using Fiddler. All the pre-written code is work well.

Comment: You should have mentioned errors you're getting

Comment: What you pass to `RestClient` constructor is base url, and what you pass to `RestRequest` is resource, which is appened to base url. So you need to do something like `var client = new RestClient("http://www.dictionary.com/browse/"); var request = new RestRequest("computer", Method.GET); var response = client.Execute(request)`

Comment: Try https://tmenier.github.io/Flurl/, it is so much more intuitive than RestSharp IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Your code won't compile since `client.Execute(request)` returns an object which implements the `IRespResponse` interface while you declared the `response` variable as of `RestResponse` type. There is no implicit conversion between this type and interface, so the compliler prevents you from making a logical error: the class `RestResponse` does implement `IRestResponse`, but it also may contain other fields and methods. You may safely cast from an interface to this type but not vice versa.

If you replace your declaration `RestResponse response` with `IRestResponse response` you will make your code compile and it actually works. However I'd recommend to examine [C# basics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tour-of-csharp/interfaces)